# A reconnecting websocket can't connect to the server with FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() being resolved to null

Tags: tomcat, jsf, websocket, weld, jsf-2.3

I have a plain Tomcat 8.5.47 having the following dependencies installed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

CDI seems to work fine, or at least, I didn't bump into any issues migrating `@ManagedBean`s to `@Named`. Having CDI installed means I can inject a `PushContext` and send some messages from the server to the client.

I declared a simple bean

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named("ButtonController")
public class ButtonController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    @Setter
    @Push(channel = "someChannel")
    private PushContext _someChannel;

    public void onPress() {
        _someChannel.send("...");
    }

}
```

and a channel in a JSF template

```
<f:websocket channel="someChannel"
             onmessage="_onmessage"
             onopen="_onopen"
             onclose="_onclose"
/>
```

with the callbacks printing a console message.

```
<h:outputScript>
    function _onopen() {
        console.log('_onopen')
    }
</h:outputScript>
```

When I load a page with the socket defined in it, the socket is being opened and a message in the console appears.

```
_onopen
```

Then I go to the network tab in the browser and see a HUGE number of requests being actively sent. Here's one of them.

```
Request URL: ws://localhost:10000/bg/javax.faces.push/someChannel?55685979-de8b-4a27-b497-f726cbea02ca
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 101

Connection: upgrade
Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 10:46:22 GMT
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: L4F6dcI3YMvkvsRhG7IyGCWYxuI=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate;client_max_window_bits=15
Upgrade: websocket
```

I assume it's due to a reconnecting websocket that fails to re-establish the connection. I go to the server log and, indeed, see this exception repeated over and over again.

```
16-Jun-2020 13:15:54.153 SEVERE [http-nio-10000-exec-2] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.getBeanReferenceByType(CdiUtils.java:230)
        at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.getBeanReference(CdiUtils.java:213)
        at com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketSessionManager.getInstance(WebsocketSessionManager.java:240)
        at com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketEndpoint.onOpen(WebsocketEndpoint.java:88)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:133)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:856)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I debug the stacktrace and get puzzled over this method.

```
public static <T> T getBeanReference(Class<T> type, Annotation... qualifiers) {
    return type.cast(getBeanReferenceByType(Util.getCdiBeanManager(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()), type, qualifiers));
}
```

where `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns `null` resolving the CDI manager to `null` which causes the exception. It's quite understandable since no JSF artifacts is being touched on the way meaning either CDI being configured incorrectly or I am missing something.

Another thing that caught my eye is the way `WebsocketSessionManager` is retrieved and the comment along that.

```
/**
 * Internal usage only. Awkward workaround for it being unavailable via @Inject in endpoint in Tomcat+Weld/OWB.
 */
static WebsocketSessionManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = getBeanReference(WebsocketSessionManager.class);
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Any nudge is really welcomed. Thanks.

---

Update:

I noticed `com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer` looks for

```
org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletContainerInitializer
```

in this bit

```
    Class<?> tyrusInitializerClass;
    try {
        tyrusInitializerClass = cl.loadClass("org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletContainerInitializer");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        // No possibility of WebSocket.
        return;
    }
```

and I was wondering if I needed to have this dependency.

---

Update 2:

I found these issues that seem related:

- [Websocket CdiUtils NPE using <f:websocket />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300380/websocket-cdiutils-npe-using-fwebsocket)
- https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4306

Comment: 1: jsf `f:websocket` is JSF 2.3 not JSF 2.2 2: if you tag it weld instead of generic CDI (even if it is CDI related) you imply it works with e.g. openwebbeans and not with weld. 3: By tagging tomcat you imply it works in e.g. Jetty. Tags are for what is proven to be a part of the problem and not for what you use.

Comment: On-topic: Can you try with MyFaces instead of Mojarra? Just for this test? Or a newer version of Mojarra?

Comment: Tomcat already provides javax.websocket out the box. Mark it provided in pom and retry. Just to exclude classpath pollution from being the cause.

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the edit, I tried the latest MyFaces - didn't change a thing, same with Mojarra (2.3.9 and 2.4.0)

Comment: @BalusC thanks, it was already "provided". Do you know if I need to have `org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletContainerInitializer` in order to initialise web sockets properly?

Comment: Nope, that's not your responsibility. That's server's responsibility. Moreover, Tomcat doesn't use Tyrus as websocket impl. This is in the end likely a bug in Mojarra. It should have falled back to non-FacesContext-dependent ways in order to obtain CDI bean manager. That problem is in turn not related to websockets, it just happened to be one of the possible triggers of that problem. In the meanwhile, you could workaround it by using OmniFaces o:socket instead of f:websocket. It's basically exactly the same. OmniFaces one only doesn't depend on FacesContext in order to obtain CDI bean manager.

Comment: @BalusC thanks, seems like OmniFaces is my only choice at the moment with the current stack. Which version would you recommend? I assume I can't use the latest one since it needs CDI 2, but I should be fine with 2.7.5

Comment: @BalusC interesting note:  I used OmniFaces 1.14.1 before CDI, now with CDI I switched to 2.7.5 and it broke my reading of `f:viewParam`s. They are no longer being set even though they are present in `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()` on the post-construct of the bean they are targeted to. Maybe they are to set before the bean is ready... But I tried to inject them, and it works fine, so probably I will rewrite the `f:viewParam` declarations to `@Inject @Param(name = "myParam")`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem with Tomcat 9 and JSF 2.3

Comment: This link has more information: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4306 - It sounds like WebSocket in Tomcat is broken.